# How to Add Static IP With Different Subnet Gateway

Tags: networking, server

i am new in Ubuntu and i am having a issue in ubuntu. i have install the Ubuntu 14.4 in my Exsi VM. my server provide give me IP and they said i have to use gateway as the main server IP to use this new ip in VM. but i can't configure. here is details

IP Address 62.210.28.28
 Subnet mask 255.255.255.255
 gateway 163.172.13.1

and i have put them like this in Ubuntu 14.4

address 62.210.28.28
  netmask 255.255.255.255
  gateway 163.172.13.1
  dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

but i can't get internet in my VM after doing this ..

please help me

Comment: Try this. `ip addr add 62.210.28.28/32 dev <name_of_your_nic>` then `ip route add default via163.172.13.1/32 dev <name_of_your_nic>` After this setting if work we will write them to file to make them permanent :) If not, give me output from command `ip a` and `ip route` after setting like edit of you question.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct information? Normally your next hop has to be within your subnet... otherwise you need a route to reach your gw.

Comment: after ip route add default via 163.172.13.1/32 dev eth0 i got an error "an inet address is expected rather than 163.172.13.132".